# Add existing product attributes dynamically and select all terms php, woocoommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a situation where I want to add existing attributes to product attributes and select them all programmatically so  I can generate variations from those attributes.

If I var dump wc_get_product_attribute_taxonomies I get full array of attributes, but If I var_dump (inside function) attribute_data I get:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
   array(4) {
   ["name"]=>
   string(4) "size"
   ["options"]=>
   object(WP_Error)#1842 (3) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["invalid_taxonomy"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "Invalid taxonomy."
    }
  }
  ["error_data"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["additional_data":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
["visible"]=>
int(1)
["variation"]=>
int(1)
}
[1]=>
array(4) {
["name"]=>
string(5) "color"
["options"]=>
object(WP_Error)#1841 (3) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["invalid_taxonomy"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "Invalid taxonomy."
    }
  }
  ["error_data"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["additional_data":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
["visible"]=>
int(1)
["variation"]=>
int(1)
  }
}
```

Problem is that I can add existing attributes but terms are not adding in $option_term_ids[];

```
    function add_generated_attributes_to_product_samp($product_id, $attributeNameFirst, $attributeNameSecond)
    {

    global $product;
    $product = new WC_Product();

    $attributeSlugFirstFinal = 'pa_' . $attributeNameFirst . '-' .  $product_id;

    $atributeTermsFirst = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => $attributeSlugFirstFinal,
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    $attributeSlugSecondFinal = 'pa_' . $attributeNameSecond . '-' .  $product_id;

    $atributeTermsSecond = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => $attributeSlugSecondFinal,
        'hide_empty' => false
    ));

    $attributes_data = array(
        array('name' => $attributeNameFirst,  'options' => $atributeTermsFirst, 'visible' => 1, 'variation' => 1),
        array('name' => $attributeNameSecond,  'options' => $atributeTermsSecond, 'visible' => 1, 'variation' => 1),
    );


    if (sizeof($attributes_data) > 0) {
        $attributes = array();


        foreach ($attributes_data as $key => $attribute_array) {
            if (isset($attribute_array['name']) && isset($attribute_array['options'])) {

                $taxonomy = 'pa_' . wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name($attribute_array['name']) . '-' . $product_id;


                $option_term_ids = array();


                foreach ($attribute_array['options'] as $option) {
                    if (term_exists($option, $taxonomy)) {

                        wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $option, $taxonomy, true);

                        $option_term_ids[] = get_term_by('name', $option, $taxonomy)->term_id;
                    }
                }
            }

            $attributes[$taxonomy] = array(
                'name'          => $taxonomy,
                'value'         => $option_term_ids,
                'position'      => $key + 1,
                'is_visible'    => $attribute_array['visible'],
                'is_variation'  => $attribute_array['variation'],
                'is_taxonomy'   => '1',

            );


            update_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', $attributes);
             
         
        }
    }
}

add_generated_attributes_to_product_samp(292547, 'size', 'color');
```